# Cargar un xib a mi .swift

Tags: swift

estoy tratando de usar mi clase llamada: `TableViewCellPropia` que extiende a `TableViewCell` como cell prototipo de mi `TableView`.
A mi cell prototipo la enlaze con un .xib para así poder graficarla mejor.

Imagenes del proyecto:

[image: Código de mi clase cell]
[image: Mi .xib]

¿Como puedo en el método siguiente, instanciar mi celula prototipo para así usarla?

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo, necesitas relacionar el `XIB` de la celda, con la subclase de `UITableViewCell` para así poder instanciarla después. Para hacerlo, hay que hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después, has de crear los `@IBOutlets` necesarios para poder acceder a la `UILabel` y el `UIButton` que tiene la celda personalizada.

```
class CeldaPersonalizadaCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Una vez hecho todos estos pasos, ya podrás instanciar la celda en el `UIViewController` donde tengas el `UITableView`.
Primero de todo, tienes que registrar el `XIB`:

```
// Registramos la celda en el tableView
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CeldaPersonalizadaCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

Y después, ya en el método delegado puedes instanciar la celda:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CeldaPersonalizadaCell

    // Configuración de la celda

    return cell

}
```

Por último, recuerda asignar los delegados correspondientes del `UITableView` tal que `UITableViewDataSource` y `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: Muchas gracias!